# MLE for normal distribution with same mean and variance/standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Could someone please let me know how to find the MLE of $\theta$ when we have a random sample from pdf $N(\theta,\theta^2)$ and from pdf $N(\theta,\theta)$?

I found an old thread that referred to [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9ByccYe5aI4C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=%22normal%20distribution%22%20%22equal%20mean%20and%20variance%22&source=bl&ots=mlfAEP4lKU&sig=l-OTgR3xmm9zTLUrdxBFyl429qw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5qttUa2zJYKwPP64gfgC#v=onepage&q=%22normal%20distribution%22%20%22equal%20mean%20and%20variance%22&f=false) book but the author does not provide the steps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is also addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101208.