# Derivation of change of variables of a probability density function?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, density-function, jacobian

In the book *pattern recognition and machine learning* (formula 1.27), it gives

$$p_y(y)=p_x(x) \left | \frac{d x}{d y} \right |=p_x(g(y)) | g'(y) |$$
where $x=g(y)$, $p_x(x)$ is the pdf that corresponds to $p_y(y)$ with
respect to the change of the variable.

The books says it's because that observations falling in the range $(x, x + \delta x)$ will, for small values of $\delta x$, be transformed into the range $(y, y + \delta y)$.

**How is this derived formally?**

---

Update from  Dilip Sarwate

The result holds only if $g$ is a strictly monotone increasing or decreasing function.

---

Some minor edit to L.V. Rao's answer
$$  \begin{equation}
    P(Y\le y) = P(g(X)\le y)=
    \begin{cases}
      P(X\le g^{-1}(y)), & \text{if}\ g \text{ is monotonically increasing} \\
      P(X\ge g^{-1}(y)), & \text{if}\ g \text{ is monotonically decreasing}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$
Therefore if $g$ is monotonically increasing
$$F_{Y}(y)=F_{X}(g^{-1}(y))$$
$$f_{Y}(y)= f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))\cdot \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$$
if monotonically decreasing
$$F_{Y}(y)=1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y))$$
$$f_{Y}(y)=- f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))\cdot \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$$
$$\therefore f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left | \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y) \right |$$

Comment: The result holds only if $g$ is a strictly monotone increasing or decreasing function. Draw a graph of $g$ and puzzle it out using the basic idea behind the definition of the derivative (not the formal definition with epsilon and delta). Also, there is an answer by @whuber on this site which spells out the details; that is, this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Your book's explanation is reminiscent of the one I offered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14490/919.  I also posted a general algebraic method at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101298/919 and a geometric explanation at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4223/919.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thanks for your explanation, I think I understand the intuition, but I'm more interested in how it can be derived using the existing rules and theorems :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f$.
Let $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ is a monotonic function.

The function $g$ could be either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. If $g$ were monotonically increasing, then the pdf of $Y$  is obtained as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y\le y) &=& P(g(X)\le y)\\
&=& P(X\le g^{-1}(y))\\
or\;\;F_{Y}(y)&=& F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)),\quad \mbox{by the definition of CDF}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
If $g$ instead were monotonically decreasing, then we would have to swap the inequality signs, since $g^{-1}$ is also monotically decreasing (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Strictly_Monotone_Function)):
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y\le y) &=& P(g(X)\le y)\\
&=& P(X\ge g^{-1}(y))\\
or\;\;F_{Y}(y)&=& 1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)),\quad \mbox{by the definition of CDF}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

By differentiating the CDFs on both sides w.r.t. $y$ and using the chain rule, we get the pdf of $Y$.
If the function $g$ is monotonically increasing, then the pdf of $Y$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
f_{Y}(y)= f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))\cdot \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)
\end{equation*}
and other hand, if it is monotonically decreasing, then the pdf of $Y$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
f_{Y}(y)= - f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))\cdot \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)
\end{equation*}
Since $\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right| = -\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$ if $\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y) \le 0$ (which will be the case if $g$ is monotonically decreasing) and $\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right| = \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$ if $\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\ge 0$ (which will be the case if $g$ is monotonically increasing), then the above two equations can be combined into a single equation:
\begin{equation*}
\therefore f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))\cdot \left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|  
\end{equation*}

Comment: But as the integral over fx must sum to 1 and fy is  a scaled version of fx, doesn't that mean fy is not a proper pdf, unless the jacobian in the abs() is 1 or -1?

Comment: @Chris The Jacobian of $g^{-1}$ is not necessarily a constant function, so it can be >1 in some places and <1 in others.

Comment: I believe the above derivation is incorrect. When $g(.)$ is monotonically decreasing, $g(X) \le y \implies X \ge g^{-1}(y)$. The minus sign does not magically appear.

Comment: The minus sign comes from the fact that the inequality is switched for monotonically decreasing transformations

Comment: Where is the justification/explanation of the bit about monotonicity

Comment: ive added some edits that should resolve all the comments.